# python os.open() with file permissions

Tags: python, operating-system, file-permissions

## python os.open()

when i try `os.open('filename',O_CREAT,0o766)` i expect the file with permissions `rwx-rw-rw` in `ls -l` command but i get the permissions as `rwx-rw-r--`  and i am unable to find the problem. and it happens same with the mask of `0o777` where the file permissions are given as `rwxrwxr-x` , missing write permission for the group , I do not know what's wrong.

expecting a solution or correction

Comment: ["When computing mode, the current umask value is first masked out."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.open). What *is* the umask on your system?

Comment: yeah i got it,  it is performing xor with umask i guess before creating the file . i set my umask to  000 and it works. it was 002 before (i guess thats why it was leaving the write bit empty). thanks for your help.